# Browser rendering

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

We are in the process of anylizing the page performance, i would like to know if we have like 10 images , 2 css , 3 JS files. How is IE 7 , 8 actually how render the content.

-> Is it like, it call the resources parllelly or is there any limit on the sequancy it calls all this resources.? Or it has like threds in built which will automatically handle.
-> If we have a JS call towords the end of the page which logs on entry to Anylitics (Pure JS call on client side) , will it wait until the calls finishes to render the page? or it will render what it has on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try Yahoo's yslow plugin for Firefox. It'll show what can be improved.

Comment: OP asks "How is IE 7 , 8 actually how render the content."

Answer (score 0):

In IE putting your javascript at the bottom, right before `</body>` is a good practice because it does not interfere with the loading of your page. You don't have to worry about Google Analytics slowing down the "DOM Loaded" event, which is the point at which the browser begins rendering the site. Put your CSS and images early in your HTML as those can be loaded in parallel (depending on browser settings). Putting javascript above those can cause a page to load slower by preventing parallel loading, which is why it is usually recommended to put them at the end (depends on what your javascript does, though).

Comment: Since it also a call to exter site will wait for the content show up?

Comment: no, it starts rendering right away. The download should happen in parallel.